# Preloading Animation - Display on click

Tags: javascript, css-animations

I'm working on a simple page but got stuck with trying to get a preloader animation (automatically animates on page load) to only display after click on a button.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/nuski/pen/PyWzvY)

I've attempted to change

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
```

To

```
document.getElementById("Loadthis")addEventListener("click", function(event) {
```

However, now the text animation doesn't display on load, but the animated icon loads on load (endlessly).

I'm attempting to have a button on page, display this style of loading screen.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing a `.` - copy-paste error, or is that your actual code? It's in your second line - should be `document.getElementById("Loadthis")`**`.`**`addEventListener("click", function(event) {...})`

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing out. I corrected but observed the same behavior of the animation loading. I've forked the original codepen which recreates what i'm experiencing here (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LaROKL)